# vim - how to set fix path as working directory

Tags: vim, text-editor, pwd

I have this issue. Let's suppose I have the following directory tree:

```
diffchar/
├── README.md
├── autoload
│   └── diffchar.vim
├── demo.gif
├── doc
│   ├── diffchar.txt
│   └── tags
├── example1.png
├── example2.png
└── plugin
    └── diffchar.vim
```

If I open `diffchar.vim` under `autoload`, the working directory will be set to `/path/to/diffchar/autoload`. I explicitly specify `:cd /path/to/diffchar`, but if I open `diffchar.txt`, the working directory will be set to `/path/to/diffchar/doc`.

Any idea how to set the working directory to a fix path and that it does not change when I open files under different directories?

Comment: Food for your thought: what *you* want is the default behaviour, that *you* explicitly altered by setting a specific option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have `autochdir` (see [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file)) set to on. Check with this vim command

```
:set autochdir?
```

If the output just says `autochdir` and not `noautochdir`, then you have it set. Turn it off by doing:

```
:set autochdir !
```